# Эмулятор в android studio не всегда запускается корректно

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Доброго времени суток!

Столкнулся с такой проблемой что эмулятор в Android Studio запускается через раз, иногда эмулятор нормально запускается, а иногда вроде как запустился а вроде и нет.

*Проц на AMD, ОП Windows10.*

1. Нажимаю "Run". Начинается загрузка эмулятора. после появляется окно с эмуляторов.

Верхняя панель управления телефоном иногда бывает активной. Даже можно сделать скриншот экрана телефона.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во вкладке Device указано что эмулятор запущен, если повторно запустить эмулятор из этого окна появится ошибка что эмулятор уже запущен.
*Пробовал удалять эмуляторы и устанавливать много раз. Не помогло*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Есть окно с ошибками видимо ответ здесь.** добавлял различные папки и файлы в папку Android Tools в ручную.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что мной было попробовано:

1. Удалял/устанавливал эмуляторы (много раз).
2. Удалял/устанавливал Android Emulator (много раз).
3. Hypervisor установлен (хотя SDK показывает что нет - там ручная распаковка и установка). (может конечно я его усыновил не правильно, но до этого эмулятор вообще ошибку выдавал).
4. В компонентах Hyper-V включён
5. Через БИОС эмуляцию разрешил.

**Подскажите пжл куда капать.**

Comment: Hyper-V только вреден. А так эмулятор - бажная штука. Периодически после очередного аптейда приходится то вручную запускать, то переустанавливать образы, то качать бета-версии эмулятора или делать даунгрейд. Вот на текущий момент (эмулятор у меня запускается не во вкладке) вылетает мессаджбокс wait debugger и только после нажатия на кнопку на нем начинает стартовать. Выключите для начала "запуск в панели" и увидите проблему, а лучше из консоли попробуйте

Comment: Когда эмулятор не стартует, зайди в процессы и убей adb.exe. Это он почему-то остаётся запущенным.